# How to install GoDaddy SSL certificates in Tomcat without CSR?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, keytool

One of our clients purchased wild card SSL certificates (*.example.com) 
from GoDaddy and he simply downloaded without giving CSR data. We have 3 files in that zip file. Those are `fce4f111a61ea3f4.crt`, `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` and `gdig2.crt.pem`.

I searched so many articles regarding this but everyone is saying first take the CSR data from your server and past it in the GoDaddy for getting SSL certificates.

In my case we didn't provide CSR data to GoDaddy, which means I don't have the keystore file.

Now, I tried to install certificates without keystore to my server. For that I used the below commands with no success:

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file fce4f111a61ea3f4.crt

keytool -import -alias interm -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gdig2.crt.pem
```

Comment: Looks ok. Your Tomcat does not need any Certificate Signing Request (CSR). This is needed to request the signing from your Certificate Authority (CA) namely GoDaddy in this case. You don't want to send them (or anybody at all) your secret private key, so you send a CSR that contains your public key and request meta data only and get back the newly crafted certificate plus intermediate certificate chain bundle. What's your actual question?

Comment: I installed SSL certificates so many times with other providers and I never send CSR data to third party but it worked for me. This time by using goDaddy certificates is not working I don't know why ?

Comment: It's to hard guess what 'not working' means without a full Exception stack trace or even knowing what the certificate is to be used for.

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you already have keystore maintained as per your statements above. Take a backup of your keystore first in order to avoid any mishap.

Apart from the files you have, you should also has **Private Key** of your generated certificate.

Now follow the steps as ordered.

1. Delete any existing entries from keystore file first.

```sh
keytool -delete -alias tomcat -keystore domain.jks
```

*You may also view any other existing entries by* `keytool -list -keystore domain.jks` *delete them as well.*

2. Now export the certificate and private key into PKCS12 file

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fce4f111a61ea3f4.crt -inkey private.key -out cert_and_key.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -caname root
```

*If you receive similar to following error*

```
unable to load private key
139995851216720:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

*It means your `private.key` isn't in proper format, you need to change encoding to `ASCII text` run following command to convert your private key*

```sh
# You can do a dry run before manipulating the actual file
tail -c +4 private.key | file -

# Change encoding
tail -c +4 private.key > private.key
```

3. Import PKCS12 file into JKS keystore:

```sh
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert_and_key.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -alias tomcat -keystore domain.jks
```

4. Now import root certificate into JKS keystore *(with root alias)*

```sh
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file $certdir/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -noprompt -keystore domain.jks
```

5. Add following in `server.xml`

```xml
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" maxThreads="150"
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/path/to/keysore/domain.jks" keystorePass="xxxxxx"
    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" />
```

*Don't forget to replace `xxxxxx` with your JKS keystore password and `keystoreFile` parameter*

6. Done. Now restart your **Tomcat server** and listen to your log file

```sh
sudo service tomcat7 restart
sudo tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

**Note:** replace `domain.jks` with your actual keystore file.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It works for me.
I have generated the certificate with the csr of different server and I have one server where tomcat is already running with key store. So when my certificate get expired, i get new certificate, so I want to add that new one. and for this it helps me

Comment: I tried this, and it worked... sort of. Web browsers accept the certificate, but Android does not. Seems like it is missing the intermediate or root certificate. "The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store). If you bought the certificate from a trusted authority, you probably just need to install one or more Intermediate certificates. Contact your certificate provider for assistance doing this for your server platform."

Comment: Step 2 should specify `-chain` (will fix @James problem). Step 3 is not needed; Java 8u60 up (since 2015) can read PKCS12 directly (and even before that if you specify keystoreType). Step 4 is not needed at all. In step 5 it shouldn't be necessary to override the default for ciphersuites, but if you do you should include AEAD (GCM and ChaCha when available) and absolutely should not include RC4.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 if we don't do step 3 and step 4, then how does step 5 work, since we have not touched domain.jks?  Step 2 creates "cert_and_key.p12", which is only used in step 3.  Just making sure I am not missing something.

Comment: @TonyB: in step 5 set the connector to use the p12, and no jks is needed at all. Step 4 supposedly adds (a copy of) the root, which isn't needed in the first place _and_ is already in the p12 after correcting step 2, but in fact step 4 is wrong and doesn't import the root at all.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ahh, so change `domain.jks` to `cert_and_key.p12`.  Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Following the info here and other places, this worked for me on TC9 on windows:

1. Make sure path has a Java Home:

   set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin
2. Create keystore:

   keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore mydomain.jks
3. Extract .csr:

   keytool -certreq -alias server -file C:\pathtoit\csr.txt -keystore mydomain.jks
4. Give csr.txt to godaddy and obtain the certificate
5. Import the bundle and the .crt file:

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -keystore mydomain.jks

   keytool -import -alias server -keystore mydomain.jks -trustcacerts -file 24234234.crt

Note: use Keystore Explorer if you want to see what's happening.

Then in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100"
  minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
  enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
  acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
  SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
  sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server"
  keystoreFile="C:\pathtoit\mydomain.jks" keystorePass="xxxx"  />
```

Comment: That's correct only for the case where you generate the key and CSR, which is not the case this question is about. Note -import with the bundle file actually imports only the intermediate CA cert 'gdig2' not the cross and root certs, but that's okay because in practice nowadays the GoDaddy G2 root is known so you don't need the cross (and in an SSL/TLS server you never actually need the root).